# Docker import fails -- "Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): file exists"

Tags: docker, import, tar, file-exists

I'm trying to `docker import` an image, resulting with the error in the topic. My suspicion is that it's due to hardlinks; it's the pattern I've witnesses trying to figure it out, but have no real idea how to sort.

The exact steps I'm taking are: fetch image manifest -> fetch layer blobs -> extract each layer chronologically -> archive directory -> `docker import`. Note: this is done in order to avoid the CLI; I'm aware of `pull` :)

This happens with a couple of images, but for example we can look at https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/.

More info:

Running as root; docker host is a remote VM (doesn't seem to make a difference)

OS:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14
BuildVersion:   18A391
```

Edit:

More useful info -- I've tried to iteratively create an image out of each layers. The first couple of layers worked... (importing 1, 1+2, 1+2+3...), but a specific layer caused this error when trying to import.

I've extracted that layer, and didn't really find anything useful... recap:

```
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ mkdir ./image
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ tar xf sha256\:f7e2b70d04ae3f516c08c24d88de0f82699aaf3ee98af6eb208bd234136142b4 -C ./image/
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ tar xf sha256\:744aedb7995c4cdfa910eed9f3035bdfe6c1670cb8c34b155955961d4123ca79 -C ./image/
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ tar xf sha256\:07afe22f8a5850183a444ea563d5b16a0218245dda6ee319c286f72c3e8ea552 -C ./image/
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ tar xf sha256\:c7bf4f31c4a4525e2fb402df85bfbd733cd3bfb13560584e4d4ce08b019bb86c -C ./image/
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ tar xf sha256\:c7bf4f31c4a4525e2fb402df85bfbd733cd3bfb13560584e4d4ce08b019bb86c -C ./image/
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ tar xf sha256\:b528e75732cc2db8e3a6d66b13717930f34e079efdfe5184da66848842a72c6f -C ./image/
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ tar xf sha256\:27e7d214ded21411ee7ddaf176b4449d75fa93693be7735ad851a31c83ab9791 -C ./image
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ tar cf image.tar -C ./image/ .
Leons-MacBook-Pro:layers_cache leongold$ docker import image.tar
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): file exists
```

Up until the last layer, `import` works. That layer basically only has apache related configuration, so I think the hardlinks theory is off.

Comment: A code sample would be really helpful.  I think all of the standard APIs have "pull" as a top-level operation; you shouldn't need to do these steps by hand unless you have a really unusual use case.  I'd generally suggest avoiding `docker import` as a matter of principle.

Comment: can you please provide more info - how can we reproduce such an error?

Comment: @DavidMaze, you can do this by hand (I've tried this, leads to the same results); fetch manifest, fetch layers & extract, archive all layers and attempt to import.

we want to incorporate our own caching logic, making the CLI not usable.

Comment: @Efrat, steps are outlined in the questions --
1) fetch layers
2) extract layers
3) archive all extract layers into a single archive
4) attempt to `docker import`.

Note: this works for most images.

Comment: yeah what were the commands? id like to run them myself

Comment: @Efrat, the first 2 steps (fetching manifest & fetching layer blobs are documented here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image)

I'm downloading the layers to a directory, and extract them all in the correct order one by one (`tar xf`). I then archive the folder I extracted the layers in (`tar cf`).

The last step is to `docker import` the archive. This typically works, however fails with `file exists` for some images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the exact cause, but extracting layers by one is definitely not the way to go; layers are supposed to be unified rather than accumulated.

I went the `docker load` route, basically implementing https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/download-frozen-image-v2.sh, which seems to work well.